# How to create an unauthenticated route in React-admin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I'm searching to create an unauthenticated route on React-Admin. I put my route out of the admin component but it doesn't works, it always call my checkAuth function in the authProvider and i don't know how to disable it just for this route.
My code below

```
<>
    <CustomRoutes>
      <Route path="/products/:slug" element={<AddRecipients/>} />
    </CustomRoutes>
    <Admin dataProvider={DataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
      <Resource name="users" list={UsersList} show={UsersShow} edit={UsersEdit} create={UsersCreate} icon={PeopleIcon} />
      <Resource name="candidatures" list={CandidaturesList} show={CandidaturesShow} edit={CandidaturesEdit} create={CandidaturesCreate} icon={NoteAltIcon} />
      <Resource name="recipients" list={RecipientsList} show={RecipientsShow} edit={RecipientsEdit} create={RecipientsCreate} icon={QuestionAnswerIcon} />
      <Resource name="jobs" list={JobsList} show={JobsShow} edit={JobsEdit} create={JobsCreate} icon={WorkIcon} />
      <Resource name="companies" list={CompaniesList} show={CompaniesShow} edit={CompaniesEdit} create={CompaniesCreate} icon={ApartmentIcon} />
    </Admin>
    </>
```

The customRoutes always call the checkAuth so it redirects me on the login page
The route i want to reach is /products/:slug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove authentication on core view elements such as `<List>`, `<Show>`, `<Create>` and `<Edit>` with the [disableAuthentication](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Create.html#disableauthentication) property.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, first thanks for your answer ! But when i'm trying to use disableauthentication on my view element, it always redirect me on the login page

Comment: Hello, first thanks for your answer ! But when i'm trying to use disableauthentication on my view element, it always redirect me on the login page. I just wanna display another resource but with no authentication

Comment: Hi, please I also need answer to this question. As Lebonsavane said, it does not work that way. I have tried the same, not working. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qo4dbm?file=src%2FcustomRouteLayout.tsx) for an example. You can logout and browse to `/custom3` and it will display the list of posts without requiring to log in.